# Output only the ping latency when using the ping command in python

Tags: python, ping

```
import subprocess
ping = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "youtube.com", "-n", "1"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE,stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output = ping.communicate()
```

The the above code is what I am using to ping a server once in Python, I am then able to output the result of the ping to the python Idle, which I will use later in the program. However the problem I have is that I do not want all of the output provided:

```
print(output)
# below is the output from this command
(b'\r\nPinging youtube.com [216.58.208.174] with 32 bytes of data:\r\nReply from 216.58.208.174: bytes=32 time=17ms TTL=54\r\n\r\nPing statistics for 216.58.208.174:\r\n    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 1, Lost = 0 (0% loss),\r\nApproximate round trip times in milli-seconds:\r\n    Minimum = 17ms, Maximum = 17ms, Average = 17ms\r\n', b'')
```

So, my question to wrap up is, how would I be able to simply capture the:

```
 time = 17ms
```

(or whatever the command outputs here at the time)
 A point in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to extract the fragment of interest:

```
import re
pattern = r"Average = (\d+\S+)"
re.findall(pattern, output[0].decode())[0]
#'17ms'
```

Comment: Does this work on non-Windows machines? Or does the ping command work differently on Linux?